# Unable to Administrate Facebook Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook

Everything seems to be correctly setup except I am not getting any administrative options. I have the Social Comments Plugin working, I even have the Open Graph tags properly setup and tested using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug (Response Code:206) it does scream errors; except still no administrative options.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="">
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
<meta property="og:video" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="">
```

This is the meta tags I am using. They are all correctly implemented and tested. I tried with `fb:admins` and `fb:app_id` on there own and together. I also have my Facebook User ID and APP ID correct as well. Still no admin features.

The code I am using to make the plugin work is based on exactly what is displayed here. It comments plugin is working. So I am assuming it should all unfold.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Something I am missing or is this feature not available for the comments plugin?

**Update**
I just did another test and added a bogus User ID and the debug did not display an error and excepted the fake ID. Shouldn't it have caught that?

Comment: I am reading that Facebook only Scrapes your page once every 24 hours. Would this cause the problem? If it is can you clear this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am reading that Facebook only Scrapes your page once every 24 hours.
>   Would this cause the problem? If it is can you clear this

You can cause facebook to rescrape the page by sending your url thru the facebook linter at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint

Comment: I was just coming in here to post my answer and you beat me to it. I had the plugin setup then today added the feature to administrate. Low and below - Facebook cached my page already. I discovered the tool you mentioned above to force a clear. Perfect ... it works.